# fragment lifecycle : onCreateView() not called when using back button

Tags: android, android-fragments

**EDIT** : after some experimentation, it looks like it works as expected if I don't add the initial fragment in the xml layout. I am now doing it in my activity source code. I suppose this is how I was expected to do it ?

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating , if a fragment is removed and then added back, onCreateView() should be called.

I also can see that getView() returns null.
onDestroyView() is called but the interface of my first fragment is still displayed when back is pressed

here is the result of my sample code :

```
--launch app
I/System.out( 3765): ==== FRAGMENT1.ONCREATE
I/System.out( 3765): ==== FRAGMENT1.ONCREATEVIEW
I/System.out( 3765): ==== FRAGMENT1.ONACTIVITYCREATED (FRAGMENT1.getView = android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout@41301268

--second fragment
I/System.out( 3765): ==== FRAGMENT2.ONCREATE
I/System.out( 3765): ==== FRAGMENT2.ONCREATEVIEW
I/System.out( 3765): ==== FRAGMENT2.ONACTIVITYCREATED

--back is pressed : getView() == null and onCreateView is not called
I/System.out( 3765): ==== FRAGMENT1.ONACTIVITYCREATED (FRAGMENT1.getView = null
```

In case I am doing something wrong, here is some basic code to reproduce my issue :

my 2 fragment classes :

```
package com.test.testbackfragment;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        System.out.println("==== FRAGMENT1.ONCREATE");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        System.out.println("==== FRAGMENT1.ONCREATEVIEW");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        v.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .remove(Fragment1.this)
                        .add(R.id.fragment, new Fragment2())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
                }
            });
        return v;
    }        

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("==== FRAGMENT1.ONACTIVITYCREATED (FRAGMENT1.getView = "+getView());
    }    
}
```

and

```
package com.test.testbackfragment;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        System.out.println("==== FRAGMENT2.ONCREATE");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        System.out.println("==== FRAGMENT2.ONCREATEVIEW");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
        return v;
    }        

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("==== FRAGMENT2.ONACTIVITYCREATED");
    }    
}
```

main activity is very simple

```
package com.test.testbackfragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

and here are the 3 layouts :
main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <fragment android:name="com.test.testbackfragment.Fragment1"
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="#0000FF">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:text="THIS IS FRAGMENT1" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:text="FRAGMENT2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="#00FF00">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:text="THIS IS FRAGMENT2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Don't declare fragments in the xml layout if you plan to do transaction with them.

Comment: thanks. this is what I figured later.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. When I delete a tab and then try to create a new one, it doesn't call 'onCreateView'. How would you suggest I overcome it?

Comment: Medmed please put in your own answer and close this one. @EladAvron Tab fragments are created once only.

Comment: use FragmentTransaction.replace()

Comment: You also shouldn't handle fragment transactions from within fragments. The Host Activity should take care of all fragment transactions to keep your code clean and concise. Each class has a job to do and if you use fragments, then the hosting Activity's job is to handle the transactions for the fragments. ;)

Answer (score 1):

When the system creates this main.xml layout, it instantiates fragment specified in the layout and calls the onCreateView() method, to retrieve each fragment's layout. later on it will use same fragment instantiates. So, it won't call OnCreateView again.

If you want to create again, get an instance of FragmentTransaction from your Activity and implement as you like.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction .replace(R.id.fragment, newFragment);
// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the fragment from the stack of `FragmentManager` by using 
`FragmentTransaction.remove(your fragment)` before `BackPress` event.

or Just use the `FragmentTransaction.replace()` to load the new fragment.